# Python: can't process Windows path provided as script argument

Tags: python, windows, path

I'm trying to write a small python script to fix the capture date of my videos.
I'm on Windows and I want to use the "SendTo" feature.

So far I'm just trying to get a list of video files based on the command line arguments:

```
import argparse
import os

vidExtension = "mp4"

def getVideoFiles(fileFolders):
    files=[]
    folders=[]

    # Create list of folders and files from command line arguments
    for arg in fileFolders:
        curpath = os.path.normpath(arg)
        print(curpath, os.path.isdir(curpath))
        if os.path.isdir(curpath):
            folders.append(curpath)
        elif os.path.isfile(curpath):
            if curpath.lower().endswith(vidExtension):
                files.append(curpath)
        else:
            print("Unrecognized arg: " + arg + "\n    normpath: " + curpath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process video files')
    parser.add_argument('foldersFiles', type=ascii, nargs='+',
                    help='Folders/Files to process')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.foldersFiles)

    getVideoFiles(args.foldersFiles)
```

When launching the script (right clic SendTo...), here is the output I get:

```
args.foldersFiles:  ["'D:\\\\Synchro NAS\\\\Images\\\\Photos Num\\xe9riques\\\\A Trier\\\\2020\\\\z Videos\\\\temp'", "'D:\\\\Synchro NAS\\\\Images\\\\Photos Num\\xe9riques\\\\A Trier\\\\2020\\\\z Videos\\\\00047.mp4'"]
'D:\Synchro NAS\Images\Photos Num\xe9riques\A Trier\2020\z Videos\temp' isdir:  False isfile:  False
Unrecognized arg: 'D:\\Synchro NAS\\Images\\Photos Num\xe9riques\\A Trier\\2020\\z Videos\\temp'
    normpath: 'D:\Synchro NAS\Images\Photos Num\xe9riques\A Trier\2020\z Videos\temp'
'D:\Synchro NAS\Images\Photos Num\xe9riques\A Trier\2020\z Videos\00047.mp4' isdir:  False isfile:  False
Unrecognized arg: 'D:\\Synchro NAS\\Images\\Photos Num\xe9riques\\A Trier\\2020\\z Videos\\00047.mp4'
    normpath: 'D:\Synchro NAS\Images\Photos Num\xe9riques\A Trier\2020\z Videos\00047.mp4'
```

Files and folders are not recognized.
I used *os.path.normpath* to normalize the paths but it doesn't work...

An important notice is that I have accentuation in the path string:
The real path is: *D:\Synchro NAS\Images\Photos **Numériques**\A Trier\2020\z Videos*

Could someone help me please :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `add_argument` call the `type` argument is set to `ascii` which calls the `ascii` function to convert the incoming string to a representation of itself (similar to `repr()`), which escapes backslashes and non-ascii characters.

This representation can't be processed as path correctly.

Solution: Omit the `type=ascii` in the call.